# Mapping between user role and resource id in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: api, wso2, roles

I want to perform resource level authorization to my APIs. My API resource URI is given by:

```
/resource/{id}
```

My goal is to show the list of {id} based on user role. Every user role has a set of {id}.
How this mapping between user role and resource id can be performed with wso2 api manager?

Answer (score 0):

You refer to [1] for this task.

According to [1], you can define a scope (can be shared or local) that belongs to a particular user role(s). For example, if you define a scope named `test` by adding the user roles `Internal/subscriber` and `admin`, and add this scope to your resource (which is `/resource/{id}`). So, only the users who have the role `Internal/subscriber` or `admin` with the scope `test` can invoke the resource.

I hope your problem will get solved by this.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-security/oauth2/oauth2-scopes/fine-grained-access-control-with-oauth-scopes/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I defined roles based on scopes but my problem is to assign a list a set of specific {id} to each role. For example : user (admin) can access id list {1,2,3}  but the user (customer) can access only {1,2}. My issue is how to assign a specific list to each scope (role)

Comment: Assigning the list of specific ids should be done from the API backend that you are using. You may write a logic to identify the users with a particular role/scope and assign the ids from your backend. I am afraid that this is out of the scope of APIM since APIM mainly do the managing tasks of an API backend.